# Has to be something simple.. but I am new to Angular

Tags: angularjs, http, repeat

This is the problem that I'm coming across...

I am returning an http to display some data in a repeat..

```
$scope.search = function() {    
    $http.get("attemptsJSON.php?q="+$scope.svalue)
            .success(function(response) {   
            $scope.attempts = response;

            });
        }'
```

That data I have a click function to return even more data. But that data is determined on the previous data which has a link to it like this.

```
$scope.getAllAtt = function(a) {
    $http.get("allAttemptsJSON.php?a="+a)
            .success(function(response) {   
        $scope.allAttempts=response;
            });
        }
```

the problem is that returned data is showing on every instance of my intial repeat and I only want it to show below the one that is clicked. I looked at so many different possibilities like Template caching, but I have no idea how to go about this I am somewhat new to Angular and I think I need to use a directive but directives confuse me. Please help.

Here is the HTML

```
        <tr ng-repeat-start="att in attempts">
            <td class="expand-col"  ng-click="getAllAtt(att.action_id)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></td>          
            <td>{{att.cust_no}}</td>
            <td>{{att.emp_name}}</td>
            <td>{{att.attemptdt}}</td>
            <td>{{att.note}}</td>
            <td>{{att.callstatus}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="x in allAttempts">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{x.note}}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>'
```

Comment: Just a tip...  I think it would make sense to create a directive for this that you would ng-repeat that would be a single attempt.  It could have it's own controller so when  you clicked it would set allAttempts on the isolated scope, and the directive template would have the `tr` you always want to display and a repeat on the one you only want if the isolated scope's allAttempts field is set...

Answer (score 1):

If you want a set of values that only belong to one item in your repeating items, then you should assign those to your repeating item, not to the whole scope:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="att in attempts">
    <td class="expand-col"  ng-click="getAllAtt(att)">
      <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></td>          
    <td>{{att.cust_no}}</td>
    <td>{{att.emp_name}}</td>
    <td>{{att.attemptdt}}</td>
    <td>{{att.note}}</td>
    <td>{{att.callstatus}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="x in att.allAttempts">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{x.note}}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

```
$scope.getAllAtt = function(attempt) {
    $http.get("allAttemptsJSON.php?a=" + attempt.action_id)
    .success(function (response) {   
        attempt.allAttempts = response;
    });
};
```

This includes some simplifications since I don't have access to your HTTP sources or CSS, but it demonstrates the concept:

http://jsfiddle.net/femt86u9/

Comment: This makes sense however when I get console log the attempt.allAttempts it tells me it is not defined.. I'm kind of confused can you define temporary variables without $?

Comment: @DanCzarnik Can you show me the code you are trying that includes `console.log`? _"can you define temporary variables without $"_ Yes, of course you can.

Comment: I got it. I messed up my JSON object definitions in the SQL statement I was pulling with attemptnote as note, wasn't set. I'm so dumb. Thank you for your help. I didn't really explain well what I meant. I understand if I don't define something as a scope I can still return it.